# El resultado de la busqueda de un dato en una tabla de otro archivo me da siempre 0 en Macros

Tags: macros, subida-de-archivos

```
' Comprobar si los valores en B8 y B9 coinciden
If valorB9 = "Latón" Or valorB9 = "Aluminio" Or valorB9 = "Cobre" Or valorB9 = "Acero" Or valorB9 = "Inoxidable" Then
    ' Definir el archivo Excel externo
    
    
    Ruta = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Por favor seleccione un libro")
    
       
    If Ruta = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set LibroOrigen = Workbooks.Open(Ruta)
    
     
    ' Seleccionar la hoja y tabla en función de B9
    Select Case valorB9
        Case "Latón"
            Set tabla = LibroOrigen.Sheets("Datos").ListObjects("TablaDatos")
   
    End Select
    
    ' Comprobar el valor de B8 y seleccionar la columna correspondiente
  ' Comprobar el valor de B8 y seleccionar la columna correspondiente
Select Case valorB8
    Case "Redondo"
        columna = 3
        MsgBox "El valor en B8 no coincide con las opciones válidas.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub ' Salir de la subrutina en caso de no coincidencia
    End Select
    Debug.Print "Tabla seleccionada: " & tabla.Name
    Debug.Print "Columna seleccionada: " & columna
    
            
    ' Valor a buscar en la tabla
    valorBuscado = Range("B10").Value
           
    
    ' Buscar el valor en la tabla y obtener el resultado
   ' Buscar el valor en la tabla y obtener el resultado
On Error Resume Next
resultadoBusqueda = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(valorBuscado, tabla.ListColumns(columna).DataBodyRange, columna, False)
```

Debug.Print "El resultado de busqueda es: " & resultadoBusqueda
On Error GoTo 0

```
    MsgBox "Resultado de la búsqueda: " & resultadoBusqueda
    If Not IsError(resultadoBusqueda) Then
    Range("B11").Value = resultadoBusqueda
```

> Cómo pueden ver he agregado unos Debug.Print para ver los valores. Sin
> embargo el Debug.Print de resultado busqueda siempre me da 0
> que debería extraer de la columna,cuando tendría que buscar el valor de B10 en la primera fila de la columna, e imprimir el valor de la colulmna asignada no se que estoy haciendo mal, dónde esta el error para que no se vaya a Error Go to 0
> p.d.
> soy nuevo en Macros, yo se que hay variables declaradas que no he
> usado